# Highlight area on 3D image, volume

Tags: image-processing, image3d

I am trying to highlight a specific area in a 3D image, all the solution I found was for 2D images and the functions are not compatible with 3D images if anyone has a solution, I would be appreciated answering. thanks

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. It is not possible to answer your question unless you load the equation for the 3D shape you have as well the shape you want highlighted. You can copy code directly from your Input Cell and paste it in the "Edit" window. There is the `{  }` icon there to format code.

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE! Your question needs more from your side. Here it's considered helpful and polite to show your own efforts and share your data and code attempts in a well [formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX), so we can quickly see the problem you are facing. Please help us to help you and [edit your question](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) accordingly. Also, please take the [tour], it will help you understand the site. If you write an [excellent question](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3) it will inspire great answers.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

There are many ways to do this. For instance, get a sample 3D image:

```
i=Import["ExampleData/CTengine.tiff","Image3D"]
```

[image]

Define some sub-volume of it, as a binary mask:

```
sub=Binarize[GradientFilter[i,5],.1]
```

[image]

After making image translucent and changing color space you can add highlight as (which produces the image at the top):

```
ReplacePixelValue[ColorConvert[Image3D[.05ImageData[i]],"RGB"],sub->Red]
```